# Infopath publishing: "a device attached to the system..." error

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-foundation, publishing, form

I get this error when I try to publish my form (from Infopath designer) to a form library (created during publish) of a SharePoint 2010 instance:

> Infopath cannot save the following form: http://[URL]
>
> A device attached to the system is not functioning.

Everything is OK when I publish on my local sandbox.

My account is a member of the Site Collection administrators group.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Are you publishing from Windows XP?

Comment: No, it's Windows 7 SP1 x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally nailed it. WebDAV was not enabled on the IIS website.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, different solution. WebDAV was already enabled on IIS, my problem was sloppy copy and pasting of the link to the list for the InfoPath form.

In InfoPath, under Submit Options, and the data connection, ensure that the Document Library points to the list path and not a specific page

Like this:
[image]

Not this:
[image]